Updated SHA256 for tree hashing (SHA-NI acceleration)
SHA-256 has been allocated silicon on modern CPU's (SHA-NI).
256-bit hash space is considered secure even against CRQC (Cryptographically Relevant Quantum Computers).
Accelerated SHA-256 outperforms optimized BLAKE2-256 by a factor of 3.5 and BLAKE2-512 by a factor of 2 (OpenSSL).
BLAKE3 showed that tree hashing appears to be the way to go as it exploits multiple cores and CPU instruction pipelining capabilities.
Would an adjusted SHA-256 utilizing a HAIFA construction (similar to BLAKE) using tree hashing just like BLAKE3 not be an excellent hashing solution in speed and low power?
SHA-NI can also be pipelined (throughput of 2) which is wasted in serial hashing mode.
SHA-NI provides instructions for the SHA256 message schedule and performing 2 rounds of the permutation.

The answer to this question is the result of a full and complete research effort that you should expect no one but yourself to carry out.

"Would an adjusted SHA-256 utilizing a HAIFA construction (similar to BLAKE) using tree hashing just like BLAKE3 not be an excellent hashing solution in speed and low power?" For what purpose exactly? SHA-256 is plenty fast for most situations and on servers with many users parallelism is inherent. Note that parallel hashing would likely flush and then fill the data cache of the other cores, which could cause a performance penalty for the other processes.

By the way, it should be pretty easy to use a generic hash tree for those protocols that require it. I don't think that having a tree hash defined means that the whole industry switches over. That's my entire idea of tree hashing anyway; it is probably better to just define a generic solution with some specific parameters than to define one that is hash specific. Maybe it can be made a bit more efficient, but as this is about large amounts of data anyway that should not matter much percentage-wise.
